# A function that takes a string, divides it into parts of 2 characters each, and then returns an array of those parts

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to implement a `splitString` function that takes a string `str`, divides it into parts of 2 characters each, and then returns an array of those parts.

If the string contains an odd number of characters, I need to add a `'_'` after the last character.

For example:

```
splitString('123456'); *// ['12', '34', '56']*

splitString('ab cd ef'); *// ['ab', ' c', 'd ', 'ef']*

splitString('abc'); *// ['ab', 'c_']*

splitString(' '); *// [' _']*

splitString(''); *// []*`
```

```
function splitString(str) {

    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
      if (str % 2 === 0) {
        result.push(str.substring(i, i + 2));
      }
      if (str % 2 !== 0) {
        
      }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please, read the guides on [what & how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then update your question according to those. SO is a community for helping fellow programmers with their hardships - and not a code writing service, sorry.

Comment: oh, I see that you've already updated the question - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for adding your code! Please add some details on what it's doing wrong, ie input, expected output, actual output

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this. First, with your approach, I'd suggest only doing the padding once, not one every iteration.

Also `str % 2` probably isn't what you want, but rather `str.length % 2`

```js
function splitString(str) {

    const result = [];
    // force it to be even-length, padding if necessary
    if (str.length % 2 !== 0) {
      str = str + "_";
    }

    
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
      result.push(str.substring(i, i+2));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(splitString("abc"));
console.log(splitString("abcd"));
console.log(splitString(""));
```

Another option is to use a regular expression

```js
function splitString(str) {
  if (str.length % 2 !== 0) str += "_";
  // str.split will return an array like
  // ["", "ab", "", "cd"]
  // so we use `.filter` to remove the empty elements
  return str.split(/(..)/g).filter(s => s)
}

console.log(splitString("abc"));
console.log(splitString("abcd"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it with a different approach - using the `rest` and `spread` operators with a `while` loop.

Also, I suggest that the 0 length string be short circuited, as its result is always the same (`[]` - an empty `array`).

```js
const strings = [
  '123456',
  'ab cd ef',
  'abc',
  ' ',
  '',
]

const splitString = (str) => {
  if (!str.length) return []
  let arr = [...str] // creating a local variable
  let ret = [] // creating the return variable

  while (arr.length) {
    // destructuring the two characters
    const [first, second = "_", ...rest] = arr
    // adding the new items to the return array
    ret = [...ret, "" + first + second]
    // modifying the local variable, so on the next "while"
    // run it's updated
    arr = rest
  }

  return ret
}

const c = strings.map(splitString)
console.log(c)
```